# How do I get Chromium browser to always ask where to save PDF files instead of automatically displaying it within the browser?

Tags: chromium, pdf

I use Chromium Browser Version 43.0.2357.130 Ubuntu 14.04.

When I click on a PDF file hyperlink,  my browser always opens PDF files within the browser itself. I want it to instead ask me where to save it followed by downloading the file to the specified location. How do I make it do so?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by disabling the PDF extension in google chrome-browser > setting >> extension.